# How to properly detect pass through "collision" in scenekit with physics?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I have a goal (`SCNTorus` hoop) that I'm shooting `SCNSphere`'s through. I need to detect when the sphere has gone from one side, through the torus, and out the other side of the torus.

My current approach is using node `physicsBody.collisionBitMask`'s on both `SCNNode`s. With `SCNPhysicsContactDelegate`, I'm able to detect the various callbacks like [`didEnd`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicscontactdelegate/1512883-physicsworld).

While logging, I'm looking at the [`penetrationDistance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicscontact/1522870-penetrationdistance) of SCNPhysicsContact. The `penetrationDistance` is

> The distance of overlap, in units of scene coordinate space, between the two physics bodies.

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didEnd contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    let maskA = contact.nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask
    let maskB = contact.nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask
    let penetrationDistance = contact.penetrationDistance

    if (maskA == CollisionTypeOne) && (maskB == CollisionTypeTwo) {            
        print(penetrationDistance)

    } else if (maskB == CollisionTypeOne) && (maskA == CollisionTypeTwo) {
        print(penetrationDistance)
    }
}
```

What I expected was that I could compare the size/diameter of my sphere to the `penetrationDistance`. The reality is `didEnd` fires multiple times for one actual event (ball going through the hoop). The `penetrationDistance` seems too small individually to be helpful.

How do you properly detect pass through "collision" events in SceneKit?

Comment: This delegate method itself is not getting called for me :( How are you setting the physics body properties in code?

Comment: make sure you set the physics body contactTestBitMask & contact delegate

Comment: are you able to get this done?